# Using js array as stack

Tags: javascript

I think it should alert 4 times, but why it just alerted just 2 times. Is there anyone can make an explanation for me?

```
   var arr = new Array;

   arr.push("1");
   arr.push("2");
   arr.push("3");
   arr.push("4");

   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     alert(arr.pop());
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `for` loop to a `while` loop:

```
while(arr.length) {
    alert(arr.pop());   
}
```

The problem is that you remove elements from the array, so the `length` decreases, ending your `for` loop early. After 2 iterations of your `for` loop, `arr.length` is 2, and `i` is also 2, so the loop ends.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/C3Vcd/) of the above.

Comment: Excellent! I'm really a novice of programming

Comment: or another possibility is doing a  `for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is checking length every Loop so in second loop array length must be 2 (2 poped) but var i is 2 so they'll out loop

Try to use `for` or you can use

```
var arr = new Array;

arr.push("1");
arr.push("2");
arr.push("3");
arr.push("4");
var length = arr.length;
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
    alert(arr.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pop removes the element from the array, and decreases the length property. So after two loop i = 2 and the array length = 2.

```
   var arr = new Array;
   arr.push("1");
   arr.push("2");
   arr.push("3");
   arr.push("4");
   var len = arr.length;
   for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
       alert(arr.pop());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

due to pop() operation array length decrements during loop execution. So after 2 iterations, i==2 and arr.length==2